# Issue on import librosa command on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, librosa

I have installed Librosa using this command `"pip install librosa"` and it is successfully installed . But when I execute `"import librosa"` in Jupyter Notebook it gives error. Can anyone help ?
[image: Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this problem a couple of times. You can try to use pip directly from your notebook:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install <package>
```

Read [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/). It helped me a lot.